# Should I change the age of my main character at the beginning of my novel?

Tags: child-characters

In my middle grade novel, my main character is 5 years old for the first five chapters. For the rest of it, he is 12 and 13 years old, but I'm worried about the beginning. The beginning shows parts the reader will need to know about the story in order to move on, so I can't delete them since there's also hints in dialogue about some of the characters' intentions. I also contemplated moving up the MC's age to 12, but then there would be a lot of plot holes following that decision, since I crafted this story around what happened to him when he was 5 years old. I know some of you will say "you answered your own question," but please give me something more than that.

Comment: How about Flashback or mentioning from characters who witnessed those vents?

Comment: To add on to the flashback idea, what you really need to be concerned with is if the 5-year-old content is *narratively interesting* in its own right. If it only matters as context for the rest of the story, there's no reason to force it to stand on its own; if it can stand on its own... well, it's still hardly the *main* story, is it? Flashbacks can be as long and substantial as you want, and if you're worried about keeping a young audience's attention then it gives you far more opportunities to tune the structure to their needs--perhaps even going so far as to point out what's relevant why.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about using flashbacks like you said, but I've heard that flashbacks are a red flag for literary agents and publishers. I might make them flashbacks, but I'm thinking about just mentioning "seven years earlier," or something like that at the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cut it short.

In JK Rowling's first novel, there is **one** chapter concerning Harry as an infant. Elements of the plot are developed there.

This chapter serves two purposes; it establishes quickly that magic is real in this world, and it teases the plot of what turned out to  be the whole series (even though JKR had enormous difficulty just selling the first book, and there was no guarantee there would be any more books).

Harry survived some horrific thing, his parents were killed, he was an orphan that miraculously survived, escaping with a lightning-bolt shaped scar on his forehead, and nobody knows how that could have happened.

The next chapter jumps into the main story, Harry is nearly ten. We see (as is usual in Act I) his "normal life", but it doesn't last long, the letters for Harry start arriving. In Chapter Four, we start Act II; Hagrid arrives, Harry learns he is a wizard, yadda yadda.

As much as you may love your first four chapters, you need to cut them to one. If this is your first novel and you want to sell it, if you want an agent or publisher to even read it, you need to start in on your main protagonist's "Normal Life" ASAP.

Like Rowling,you might get away with a short Chapter 1 (she did 21 paperback pages, typically about 5700 words) as an introduction.

But in Chapter 2, start like Rowling; "Seven years had passed since [that stuff happened], John was thirteen now, in the eighth grade. [etc]".

Compress. I don't think you can start with four chapters where basically the plot goes nowhere and things are just happening to your protagonist.

You need to get to the Normal World where the plot takes place sooner than that.

Comment: It should be noted that J.K. Rowling's *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* **doesn't begin with Harry Potter at all**. The opening concerns the Dursleys, their normality, and the hook is how the Dursleys are "the last people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious". Over the first eight pages, ***the Dursleys* are the protagonists of the narrative** and the plot is driven by "a secret" that the Dursleys had and "their greatest fear [...] that somebody would discover it". For the rest of the first chapter the narrative switches to Dumbledore, Hagrid, and McGonagall.

Comment: We cannot therefore presuppose that the book opens with Harry at a younger age. Rather, the first chapter has the content of a typical prologue, in that it narrates what *other characters than the protagonist* do before the story begins. It just isn't named that way.

Comment: @Ben The Chapter is titled "The Boy Who Lived", the magical mystery that sets Harry Potter above all other students and of particular interest to Dumbledore and staff of Hogwarts. It's about Harry, the Dursleys are cartoonish props; not protagonists. Regardless, my point is I think it quite improbable that an unknown, previously unpublished author could ever sell a book with a 22,000 word "prologue" of four chapters to a publisher or agent.  A best-selling author can get away with just about anything, but unpublished authors need to meet expectations if they hope to sell something.

Answer (score 2):

In children's, Middle Grade, and Young Adult fiction the protagonist must have the age of your target audience<sup>1</sup>. And since you need to hook your readers from the very beginning, and identification with the protagonist is an important part of a story's attraction, your protagonist needs to be as old as your readers right from the first page.

Remember, you are not writing adult fiction, where the development of a person from childhood onwards is a common theme, but a genre with very specific and narrow conventions.

All the backstory that happens to the protagonist before the beginning of the present story arc must be revealed during the present day narrative or implied. You can use

- the protagonist thinking of his past
- characters talking about past events
- the present day situation reflecting past events<sup>2</sup>
- an omniscient narrator explaining things to the reader

---

<sup>1</sup> Usually the protagonist is at the upper end of your reader's age bracket: 14 or so for MG and 16 (or "in the last year of High School") for YA.
<sup>2</sup> For example, a visit to the grave of a dead brother.